# Photoshop Batch for different aspect ratio images

Tags: adobe-photoshop, canvas, size

I have nearly 40 thousand of product photos horizontally and vertically. Hence I need a Photoshop action that will spawn them all in the center and make them square.
I can't tell Photoshop which is vertical and which is horizontal. So I can't set the canvas size properly.

> Do you know of a script for this?

Comment: This is very similar to [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/89723). But in that, the OP wants the image to *fit* inside a square. I assume you want to *fill* the square. I'll write an answer.

Comment: If you're on a Mac, I would recommend https://www.lemkesoft.de/produkte/graphicconverter/ for this. It has a batch function that is far easier to use than PS.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recipe for an action that will crop an image with any aspect ratio into a square. It will make the image *fill* a square so the excess will get cropped away.

---

Create a new action and record the following:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl /Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all.
- Perform *Select > Transform Selection*, rotate the selection 90 degrees and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to commit the transformation.
- Perform *Image > Crop* to crop the image to the selection.

Use this action to batch all your images.

---

Be aware that using this method you might crop away parts of the image in an unaesthetic way.

Comment: use-case is is probably an e-commerce thing where the initial thumbnails are square by default. So in the rotation step, the temp layer content now has transparent letterboxing to allow for the ctrl+click selection?

Comment: @Yorik, yes after rotation the template layer has the same width as the height of the document or vice versa. The selection will be confined to the document bounds so it becomes a square.

Comment: @Yorik, btw I simplified the method. Don't know why I felt the need to add all those unnecessary steps.

Comment: I think your reduction leaves an image sideways?

Comment: @Yorik, try it out. You are not rotating the *image*, only the *selection* itself.

Comment: right, didn't read it carefully enough